# Confused about time dilation/length contraction

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, length-contraction

I have a following problem: A meson is generated $h$ meters above the earth's surface and begins to move towards the earth with velocity $v$. Its (proper) lifetime is $t_m$.

1. What is $v$ if the meson is to reach the surface of the earth?
2. How long did the meson live, according to a clock on the surface of the earth?
3. According to the meson, how far away from the surface of the earth was it created?

I familiarized myself with formulas for time dilation and length contraction. If we attach a primed frame of reference to the meson, then

$$\Delta t = \gamma \Delta t'$$
$$\Delta x = \frac{1}{\gamma} \Delta x'$$

But then, what is $v$? Is it $\frac{\Delta  x}{\Delta t}$ or $\frac{\Delta  x'}{\Delta t'}$? Clearly the two aren't the same, but I thought the velocity is 'set in stone' so to speak, regardless of the frame of reference? So what is the meaning of each of those two quantities?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?
I would suggest solving for $v$ in $\gamma$.

Comment: It's not a homework problem. I'm having trouble understanding conceptually what's going on. In particular, the diffrence between $\frac{\Delta  x}{\Delta t}$ and $\frac{\Delta  x'}{\Delta t'}$.

Comment: I can of course mindlessly substitute the quantities into the formulas, but I'm not gaining anything from that: For (1), I write $\Delta x / \Delta t = v = \frac{h}{\gamma t_m}$ and solve for $v$. For (2), just substitute into time dilation equation, and for (3) substitute into length contraction.

Comment: The question I've linked may not seem an obvious duplicate, but in my answer to it I do exactly the calculation you describe.

Comment: I agree with the answer provided in the linked question.  $v$ is $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t'}$.